# Trying to understand Apache Kafka as a microservice. Still confused

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I am learning about Kafka, and I am curious as to how a Kafka client should exist in a Microservices architecture I want Kafka to keep a log of important information, and enable automatic reaction to those information appropriately.

My question is how should Kafka exist with the backend as a microservice?

1. Stand alone client.- The Kafka client (producer/consumer) exists alone. It exposes an API for the frontend to do HTTP requests (POST, PUT), sending data. The data is then converted into events, and produced to the Kafka cluster by the Kafka client.- The consumer also lives here, and will make reactive API calls to a separate backend when necessary.
2. A layer in the backend- When the frontend makes a HTTP request (POST, PUT) to the backend, the ‘REST controller’ in the backend looks at what data is sent, and if necessary, produces it to the Kafka cluster. - The consumer also lives here, and reacts to new events internally with other services in the backend.
3. Producer in the frontend, consumer in the backend.- Frontend (React.js, Vue.js, etc) has a Kafka client that produces event of important information that requires logging. Consumer Kafka client also exists in the backend and reacts to events internally with other services. Backend also exposes an API for non-kafka requests.
   Maybe a combination of this? Or are these all wrong?

Confluent has been quite helpful so far, but I think I am missing something important to piece all of it together.

Comment: I have the feeling that all these are valid. Which one to choose depends on your exact use case and requirements!

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/